# Choosing tuples from a list that satisfy a condition in SAGE

Tags: sage

I would like to create a program that chooses certain tuples from a list of tuples that satisfy certain conditions.

Here's the basic case of what I am trying to do:

First I create a list of length 3 tuples with coordinates in the set [-1,1]:

```
Tupes=Tuples([-1,1],3)
```

And now I am trying to extract those members whose coordinates sum up to 1. I have tried running

```
[Tupes[k] for k in len(Tupes) if sum([Tupes[k][j] for j in range(len(Tupes[k]))])==1]
```

but am getting the error

`Error in lines 1-1`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "/projects/sage/sage-7.5/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 995, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

I am new to SAGE and python, so this is just an exercise I am trying to do to learn.

Comment: By the way, you might like the `IntegerVector` class ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that you are going in `len(Tupes)` which is just a number, rather than in `range(len(Tupes))` which would be a list.  You can't iterate a number, only a list.

That said, there are some other things you can do to make this tighter.  Here is [one suggestion](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwLKS1ILbYNKS3ISS3WiNY11DGM1THW5OWKDgFJRGfHKqTlFylkK2TmKRQl5qWnaoDF9ZITi1Iy8xJzMksqNTQ1FTLTFIpLczVgejRtbQ1jebkAjFAeKA==&lang=sage).

```
Tupes=Tuples([-1,1],3)
[Tupes[k] for k in range(Tupes.cardinality()) if sum(Tupes[k])==1]
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I forgot to add range(). And thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great!  If this indeed answered, be sure to check the mark so other users know they can actually use this.  It's a very common beginner issue, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat simpler than kcrisman's answer:

```
sage: Tupes=Tuples([-1,1],3)
sage: [k for k in Tupes if sum(k) == 1]
[[1, 1, -1], [1, -1, 1], [-1, 1, 1]]
```